# NPM: uninstall package with package.json

Tags: npm, npm-install, package.json

With this in package.json:

```
"devDependencies": {
  "babel-core": "6.26.3"
}
```

`babel-core` will be installed when npm install is executed.

I am working with two branches in git, each one with different dependencies, and every time I change from branch A to branch B I must uninstall certain module before running npm install command because it causes an error if I just execute `npm install`.

Is there a way to tell npm to remove a package if present when executing `npm install`? Something like

```
"devDependencies": {
  "babel-core": "6.26.3"
},
"uninstall": {
  "wepback-command": "*"
}
```

Many thanks.

Comment: add to .gitignore to exclude package.json

Comment: Many thanks, Naim, but that won't uninstall any package.

Comment: yes will not uninstall but, for next use to not conflict each other packages :)